# Getting locked out of Face ID

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, face-id

I get locked out of Face ID from my iPhone intermittently, which has happened over the last couple of years when running iOS 14, 15 and 16. This is after Face ID was used and the iPhone was locked.

It happened again this morning after I upgraded to iOS 16, last night and was playing around with it. It even happened during a flight in airplane mode. I am wondering if anyone knows what would cause that to happen, other than turning the phone back on after a power down, or not using Face ID continuously for over 48 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of causes in Apple's documentation:

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208114

The list given is:

- You’re wearing a face mask and haven’t set up Face ID with a Mask.
- The device has just been turned on or restarted.
- The device hasn’t been unlocked for more than 48 hours.
- The passcode hasn’t been used to unlock the device in the last six and a  half days and Face ID hasn’t unlocked the device in the last four hours.
- The device has received a remote lock command.
- After five unsuccessful attempts to match a face.
- After initiating power off/Emergency SOS by pressing and holding either volume button and the side button simultaneously for 2 seconds.

Comment: Receiving a Remote lock. And  the 5 unsuccessful attempts to match face.    I did know about those 2 reasons.   …..    just wandering why I could open my iPhone with FaceID inside the plane to set it in airport mode as usual before take off, and after landing 8 hrs later Face ID was no longer working..  I never used the phone at all in between.   Still trying to figure out

Comment: One of the causes listed is not using FaceID to unlock the device for a period of 4 hours. Your flight was 8 hours. Sounds reasonable.